# Excluding Blank Nodes from SPARQL query results

Tags: python, sparql, dicom, rdflib, blank-nodes

I am using RDFLib to query on the [Semantic Dicom Ontology](http://data.bioontology.org/ontologies/SEDI/submissions/6/download?apikey=8b5b7825-538d-40e0-9e9e-5ab9274a9aeb). I am querying for owl:Class in the graph constructed from the above ontology. RDFLib returns results which contain blank nodes and I wish to exclude such queries. My query -

```
from rdflib import Graph
g = Graph()
g.parse('dicom.owl')
q = """SELECT ?c WHERE {?c rdf:type owl:Class}"""
qres = g.query(q)
```

dicom.owl is the [Semantic Dicom Ontology](http://data.bioontology.org/ontologies/SEDI/submissions/6/download?apikey=8b5b7825-538d-40e0-9e9e-5ab9274a9aeb) downloaded in my machine.

Some of the results that I receive - 
[image: Results of owl class queries]

How can I modify my query to exclude all the blank nodes?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```python
from rdflib import Graph
g = Graph()
g.parse('dicom.owl')
q = """SELECT ?c WHERE { ?c rdf:type owl:Class .
       FILTER (!isBlank(?c)) }"""
qres = g.query(q)
```

---

Take a look at this family of SPARQL functions:

- [isIRI](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#func-isIRI),
- [isBlank](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#func-isBlank),
- [isLiteral](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#func-isLiteral),  [isNumeric](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#func-isNumeric).