# Jena SPARQL query without Blank Nodes in result

Tags: sparql, jena, blank-nodes

How do I create a query that just returns asserted individuals, not blank nodes (anonymous individuals) if they exist?

Here is my SPARQL query:

```
PREFIX ont: <http://ontologies/aa-CurrentOntology#>
PREFIX rdf:  <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
SELECT DISTINCT ?ind
WHERE {
    ?ind rdf:type ont:Size .
}
ORDER by ?ind
```

Here are some of the results (solutions):

```
sol: ( ?ind = <http://ontologies/aa-CurrentOntology#Big> )
sol: ( ?ind = <http://ontologies/aa-CurrentOntology#Small> )
sol: ( ?ind = _:b0 )
sol: ( ?ind = _:b1 )
sol: ( ?ind = _:b2 )
sol: ( ?ind = _:b3 )… thousands more after this
```

I want the query to only return the first two results, not the last four (_:b0, _:b1, etc). These do not exist in my input OWL file. I realize the blank nodes are probably because of the way the ontology is defined, but is there a way to eliminate them from the query result set?

I tried adding:

```
FILTER isURI (?ind)
```

...but this still requires all blank nodes to be calculated before being filtered out. Unfortunately, there seem to be thousands of blank nodes and the query never completes.

Is there a way of stating

> don't bother calculating blank nodes

?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44113648/7879193 ?

Comment: That would work if the query actually completed, I've used that solution in other situations so you are mostly correct. I've edited my question to be more clear that I need the query itself to ignore blank nodes, not just filter them out after the fact.

Comment: `?ind rdf:type ont:Size, owl:NamedIndividual`? I can't understand, why these blank nodes come into existence, please paste respective fragment of your ontology.

Comment: I wish I could but I am restricted from posting actual data. :-(

Comment: do you have reasoning enabled? I don't see why for this simple query blank nodes are returned, except you have subclass axioms with complex OWL class expressions like `:p some :Size`

Comment: Yes, reasoning is enabled. It is likely there are subclass axioms with complex OWL class expressions, like you said. I'm not the person developing the ontology structure. But I am working with them to resolve this issue.

Comment: Ok, but then it's at least clear from where the blank nodes are computed. As Stanislav said, adding `?ind rdf:type owl:NamedIndividual` should avoid class expression based nodes.